# A question about groups

Tags: group-theory

Can we make semigroups or monoids with cardinal numbers as their elements under multiplication or addition?

Comment: Yes. A related idea is the monoid of set under disjoint unions or Cartesian products. We can take this monoid, and quotient out by cardinality.

Comment: Since the title mentions groups, I might add that you'll run into problems if you want to turn cardinal addition into a group operation.  Specifically, the Grothendieck group (group of formal differences) of the additive monoid of cardinals is trivial.  Proof:  if $\alpha$ is any cardinal, and $\beta$ is an infinite cardinal greater than $\alpha$, then $\alpha + \beta = \beta$, so $[\alpha] = [\alpha + \beta] - [\beta] = [\beta] - [\beta] = 0$.